# Is it possible to run a Gazebo Classic simulation distributed across more than one machine?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-simulator, distributed-systems

Currently I'm working on a project where we use ROS2 Humble integrated with Gazebo Classic. One of our goals is to distribute the Gazebo simulation so that the Gazebo world and each robot present on the scene is located in different hosts.

However, I haven't found any Gazebo Classic documentation about distributed simulations.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "distribute the simulation". It seems like you have jumped to an answer without telling us the high-level problem you are actually facing. Please edit your question to more clearly describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that Gazebo Classic won't allow you to execute a distributed simulation unless you make some deep changes into its code base. Dealing with large simulation environments was probably one the reasons to move from Gazebo Classic to the new Gazebo.

If you migrate the code to it, the best tool to deal with large environments could be the [levels feature](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/levels.html) (see it in action [in this Linkedn post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ahcorde_gazebo-levels-simulation-activity-7087825562798292993-Q152/)). The new Gazebo also supports [distributed simulation](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/distributedsimulation.html) but it will probably be much harder to get it working correctly to gain performance than using levels.

Comment: Thank you for you response.

Reading the documentation you send I understood that Ignition can  separate the simulation by sections/levels. I think that I wasn't clear enough. What I want.

i want tranform this:

"Unique Host"
Scenario (World with camera1 and camera2) -> gazebo topics -> ros-bridges -> ROS topics

to

this:

"Host 1"
          Instance 1: camera1-> gazebo topic -> ros-bridge -> ROS topic
"Host 2"
          Instance 2: camera2-> gazebo topic -> ros-bridge -> ROS topic
"Host 3"
          World  -> gazebo topic -> ros-bridge -> ROS topic

Regards, João

Comment: Thanks João for clarifying. I think that indeed levels would not help too much with your plan given these details and without knowing more. You can give a try to the distributed simulation, it should work although it could be difficult to gain performance given the latency and the simulation overload of distributing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run a Gazebo Classic simulation distributed across
> more than one machine?

If by "simulation" you mean the gzserver o.s. process, the answer is No.